# Is there a way to update Material UI theme palette primary and secondary color at runtime?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, custom-theme

There is a set of default theme palette colors in our application, however for white labelling purpose I get theme primary and secondary color from API. Is there any way I can update those colors at runtime after receiving the values from API?

I am wrapping the MUI themeProvider at App level

```js
import { ThemeProvider, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
 import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
 
 
 const App = () => {
const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
   primary: {
      main: "#fff0c9", 
   },
   secondary: {
      main: '#FF8200',
   }
});
 
return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}> 
      <div> Component </div>
   </ThemeProvider>)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

After loading the component, an API call receive the updated primary and secondary colors for each clients. Is there any way to update it at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the desired colors in state and update that state with new colors. Then, you use that state in `createMuiTheme()` to set the primary and secondary colors. You may also want to use `React.memo()`.

Here's an example for setting random colors:

```js
const { useMemo, useState } = React;
const {
  AppBar,
  Button,
  createMuiTheme,
  CssBaseline,
  ThemeProvider,
  Toolbar
 } = MaterialUI;
 
const randomColor = () =>
  `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;

const App = () => {
  const [primary, setPrimary] = useState(randomColor);

  const theme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: { main: primary }
        }
      }),
    [primary]
  );

  const setRandomPrimary = () => setPrimary(randomColor);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar color="primary">
        <Toolbar />
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar />
      <Button onClick={setRandomPrimary}>Change Color</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

This was based on this [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#user-preference).

The random color function came from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/).